# using google map after logging

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-maps, maps

I have a project witch is using googleMap, when I used localhost googleMap works correctly and anythings is OK, but when I deploy it on the other computer the site can not work(don't show google map!!!).
I got a valid key but stil this problem exists!
please help me!

Comment: when you say "other computer" do you mean you are deploying it to google app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you manage correctly the errors from Google Map API in your code, in order to see if there is a given error returned by one of the google map function you use

Also, did you inspect the page when deployed on the other computer, with a tool like firebug/web inspector, to see if there are some errors linked to the problem

Answer (score 1):

Might it be a cross-site scripting issue?  There's an option in the GoogleMaps preferences that allows you to turn off security.  As an experiment, try turning it off to see if it makes any difference.  (And don't forget to turn it back on when you are done!)

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like an API key problem.  Make sure that you used the right domain to get your key.

If you use "example.com" to get your key, all of the sub-directories on example.com will be valid.

If that's not it, you definitely need to use Firebug to find out what the error is.